# On Mathematical Foundations of Football

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, ds.dynamical-systems, applied-mathematics, chaos

Football (soccer) is arguably one of the most unpredictable sports. Countless variables play a role in determining the outcome of a certain football match. Due to the high complexity of the entire set of involved parameters, the results of football matches may seem pretty random at the first glance. However, there are mathematical theories enabling us to model and analyze the behavior of such complex systems (e.g. chaos theory, probability, and dynamical systems).

Also, just like the case of financial markets, there is a great commercial and social motivation behind predicting football matches. For instance, if you are in charge of a company sponsoring a certain football team in an elimination tournament, you might be concerned with the number of matches that your team can play before its elimination so that you can estimate the amount of public attention and profit that you can obtain by sponsoring this certain team.

During my search I came across the following interesting papers in which some methods from dynamical systems and probability theory are used for analyzing football matches.

- K. Davids, D. Araújo and R. Shuttleworth, *Applications of Dynamical Systems Theory to Football*. ([Link to the paper](http://www.ff.ul.pt/~lgouveia/dmproj/DavidsAraujoShuttleworthSoccer.pdf))
- L. Bastos; J. da Rosa, *Predicting probabilities for the 2010 FIFA World Cup games using a Poisson-Gamma model*. J. Appl. Stat. 40 (2013), no. 7, 1533–1544. ([MR3286258](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3286258))
- G. Angelini and L. De Angelis, *PARX model for football match predictions*.
  J. Forecast. 36 (2017), no. 7, 795–807. ([MR3714406](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3714406))

Also, based on the following paper, I guess some chaos theoretic approaches might be relevant to this problem.

- M. G. Mack, S. Huddleston, K. E. Dutler, and J. K. Mintah, *Chaos Theory: A New Science for Sport Behavior?* ([Link to the article](http://www.athleticinsight.com/Vol2Iss2/ChaosPDF.pdf))

I wonder whether there is any known *really successful* and *practically applicable* mathematical method for predicting football matches or not.

> **Question.** What are examples of research papers modeling football matches/tournaments using mathematical tools (from chaos theory, dynamical systems or probability) which particularly suggest methods for **predicting** the results of the football matches/tournaments?

Comment: Football is low scoring which is a big problem, unlike basketball, say. World cup prediction has an extra difficulty. The ratings/models for the teams based on past performance form a graph that's highly connected within each confederation [say Europe] but very lightly connected [other than friendlies] for pairs of teams in different confederations [say Germany v Uruguay] other than possibly at the previous world cup, which is probably relatively old information.

Comment: (+1) You actually made a really good point concerning the essential difference between football and its *high scoring* counterparts such as basketball. I do agree with you that it makes some mathematical approaches such as the probabilistic methods quite hard.

Comment: such as one team dominating, but other one scoring a lucky goal in injury time ;-) as just happened in the Iran-Morocco match. Disclaimer: Only watched 7 minute long highlights.

Comment: @kodlu Hahaha....If it was merely based on luck, I hope it would be a point on the map of a strickly increasing continuous luck function! ;-P

Comment: Good luck to Iran, it's a team I like...

Comment: The 538 website has charts giving all sorts of win/lose/tie probabilities for the current Cup. I'm sure, it being 538, that there's some mathematics behind their predictions. I'm not sure how much they have posted about the math.

Comment: "Football (soccer) is arguably one of the most complicated sports" What does that even mean?  I mean we can make any sport as complicated as we want by simply asking for more and more accurate models.  A good enough predictive model of arm wrestling would take sun spots into account.  Do you want to cash that out somehow in terms of the change in the variance of outcomes as more factors are added to the statistical model or something?

Comment: I made the following observation about soccer once: "A lot of people seem to be interested in a spheroid's semi-random interaction with a rectangle filled with humanoids. Apparently the trajectory of the spheroid is analyzed and two integers are assigned to it. The relative ordering of these two integers is considered significant."

Comment: @PeterGerdes I mean football seems to be very hard to predict in comparison with many other branches of sports, say tennis or volleyball. In many sports it seems one can predict the result of a normal match between two teams/individuals of certain rank fairly effectively but such simple ways of prediction actually don't work when it comes to football.

Comment: I wonder whether this would be more suitable for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com). They have [predictive-models](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/predictive-models) tag and also some posts about [soccer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bpredictive-models%5D+soccer) or [football](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bpredictive-models%5D+football).

Comment: @MartinSleziak Well, I think the question is not entirely about statistics and so fits the MO scope much better. As I mention in the original post, there are some techniques from dynamical systems and probability theory that are used for modeling and analyzing football. Also, I guess some chaos theoretic approaches might be relevant to this problem. Actually, these types of mathematical approaches are what I am looking for rather than the statistical ones.

Comment: @GerryMyerson (+1) Indeed! Here is a link to one such analysis on the 538 website in which they tried to predict the World Cup 2018 ranking: https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/2018-world-cup-predictions/

Comment: @MortezaAzad That may be true but I don't think that's a function of the game itself per see as it is of the economics and system for choosing match lineups.  I bet if we required each football team to play only with players born in their home city it would suddenly be a lot easier to predict.  It's just that the market and draft function to let teams who are less good purchase better talent making them more equal in ways that can't happen in tennis.  Also, I suspect football teams schedule the blows outs for the less watched time slots.

Comment: @MortezaAzad I don't doubt your observation but I do doubt that it reflects anything about the dynamics of the game itself or the mathematics used in prediction but rather external factors which make close teams closer and aspects of the scoring system which make games seem closer than they may otherwise be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typing "mathematics of soccer" into the internet led to J.A. Tenreiro Machado, António M.Lopes, On the mathematical modeling of soccer dynamics, Communications in Nonlinear Science and Numerical Simulation, Volume 53, December 2017, Pages 142-153:

Abstract

This paper addresses the modeling and dynamical analysis of soccer teams. Two modeling perspectives based on the concepts of fractional calculus are adopted. In the first, the power law behavior and fractional-order integration are explored. In the second, a league season is interpreted in the light of a system where the teams are represented by objects (particles) that evolve in time and interact (collide) at successive rounds with dynamics driven by the outcomes of the matches. The two proposed models embed implicitly details of players and coaches, or strategical and tactical maneuvers during the matches. Therefore, the scale of observation focuses on the teams behavior in the scope of the observed variables. Data characterizing two European soccer leagues in the season 2015–2016 are adopted and processed. The model leads to the emergence of patterns that are analyzed and interpreted.

Also, [this](https://www.fourfourtwo.com/features/soccermatics-how-maths-will-change-your-understanding-football) article, Soccermatics: How maths will change your understanding of football, on the 442 website, reporting on the work of Professor [David Sumpter](https://www.bloomsbury.com/uk/soccermatics-9781472924124/). Sumpter has several math/soccer videos online.

Comment: (+1) Really interesting references, especially the videos! Thanks for introducing, Gerry! :-)

Comment: Mathematics may apply to revolutionize soccer https://gilkalai.wordpress.com/2009/04/20/the-intermediate-value-theorem-applied-to-football/ (and also https://gilkalai.wordpress.com/2011/06/09/another-way-to-revolutionize-football/ ). However this is not in the direction of predictions, and also not quite yet "really successful and practically applicable".

Answer (score 7):

There is a great article by Connes (translated in [**Symmetries**](http://www.ems-ph.org/journals/newsletter/pdf/2004-12-54.pdf),
Eur. Math. Soc. Newsl. 54, 11-18 (2004). 
[ZBL1176.00001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1176.00001). - link to free pdf, p. 11-18) motivated by fair pairings in soccer competitions, which quickly leads to nice mathematics.

Recently, Brams et al. [**Making the rules of sports fairer**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/16M1074540), SIAM Rev. 60, No. 1,
181-202 (2018). [ZBL06837609](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:06837609).
analyzed the advantage of starting a penalty shootout, and proposed fairer adjustments.

For some statistical work, see, e.g.,

*Fuster-Parra, Pilar; García-Mas, Alex; Cantallops, Jaume; Ponseti, F.Javier; Luo, Yuhua*, [**Ranking features on psychological dynamics of cooperative team work through Bayesian networks**](http://dx.doi.org/10.3390/sym8050034), Symmetry 8, No. 5, Article ID 34, 17 p. (2016). [ZBL1376.62141](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1376.62141).

*Seth, Sohan; Eugster, Manuel J.A.*, [**Probabilistic archetypal analysis**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s10994-015-5498-8), Mach. Learn. 102, No. 1, 85-113 (2016). [ZBL1352.62083](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1352.62083).

*Emparanza, Ignacio Díaz; Núñez-Antón, Vicente*, [**On the use of simulation methods to compute probabilities: application to the first division Spanish soccer league**](http://www.idescat.cat/sort/artpublished.html), SORT 34, No. 2, 181-200 (2010). [ZBL1203.62221](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1203.62221).

*Suzuki, A.K.; Salasar, L.E.B.; Leite, J.G.; Louzada-Neto, F.*, [**A Bayesian approach for predicting match outcomes: The 2006 (Association) football world cup**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1057/jors.2009.127), J. Oper. Res. Soc. 61, No. 10, 1530-1539 (2010). [ZBL1198.62177](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1198.62177).

*Yue, Zengyuan; Broich, Holger; Seifriz, Florian; Mester, Joachim*, [**Mathematical analysis of a soccer game. I: Individual and collective behaviors**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1111/j.1467-9590.2008.00413.x),  [ZBL05709770](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:05709770).

*Yue, Zengyuan; Broich, Holger; Seifriz, Florian; Mester, Joachim*, [**Mathematical analysis of a soccer game. II: Energy, spectral, and correlation analyses**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1111/j.1467-9590.2008.00414.x),  [ZBL05709771](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:05709771).

*McHale, Ian; Scarf, Phil*, [**Modelling soccer matches using bivariate discrete distributions with general dependence structure**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1111/j.1467-9574.2007.00368.x), Stat. Neerl. 61, No. 4, 432-445 (2007). [ZBL1149.62338](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1149.62338).

*Kopociński, Bolesław*, [**Components of the game result in a football league**](http://dx.doi.org/10.4064/am28-1-4), Appl. Math. 28, No. 1, 55-72 (2001). [ZBL1008.62548](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1008.62548).

*Dyte, D.; Clarke, S.R.*, [**A ratings based Poisson model for World Cup soccer simulation**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1057/palgrave.jors.2600997), J. Oper. Res. Soc. 51, No. 8, 993-998 (2000). [ZBL1107.62383](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1107.62383).

Comment: (+1) It is such a nice and comprehensive answer! Thank you, Olaf!